# I've been trying to find the right answer for the project Euler quiz number 8

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class LargestProductInASeries {
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    long mul;
    long bigMul = 0;


    String nodes = reader.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {

        list.add(Character.toString(nodes.charAt(i)));
        if (list.size() == 13) {
            mul = multiply();
            if (mul > bigMul) {
                bigMul = mul;
            }// whichever the biggest result, save it in save variable
            list.remove(0); // removes the first index
        }


    }
    System.out.println(bigMul);
}
public static long multiply() {
    int mul = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        mul = mul * Integer.parseInt(list.get(i));
    }
    return mul;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question, what output are you expecting, and what output are you getting?

Comment: Please get familiar with stackoverflow markdown rules for code, you have to indent everything by 4 spaces in order to get it formatted correctly. 
Moreover, nobody is going to look up "Euler quiz number 8" for you, so please specify the actual input for your program, your expected output and the actual output.

Comment: I've done this problem in Java if you want to take a look at it- http://nirajsdatabase.blogspot.com/

Comment: You should really mention what the problem is here instead of expecting us to go looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing integer math in `multiply` (and then promoting the result to `long` when you `return`). Change

```
public static long multiply() {
    int mul = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        mul = mul * Integer.parseInt(list.get(i));
    }
    return mul;
}
```

to

```
public static long multiply() {
    long mul = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        mul = mul * Integer.parseInt(list.get(i));
    }
    return mul;
}
```

However, it would be better to avoid hardcoding the length and I would not use a global (and a raw-type at that). Pass the `List` into `multiply` (and prefer `Integer` to `String`). Like,

```
public static long multiply(List<Integer> list) {
    long mul = 1;
    for (int i : list) {
        mul *= i;
    }
    return mul;
}
```

Then you can declare your `List` and simplify your `main` method with `Math.max(long, long)` like

```
long bigMul = 0;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- not a global or raw-type
String nodes = reader.next();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
    list.add(Character.digit(nodes.charAt(i), 10)); // <-- char to int
    if (list.size() == 13) {
        bigMul = Math.max(bigMul, multiply(list));
        list.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked... I don't know how i missed it... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in line 41 
from

```
int mul = 1;
```

to

`long mul = 1;`

You have declared mul variable as Integer in the beginning. But you are using it to multiply long values.

That are the main bugs in your code.

PS : In my experience, most of the people make one common mistake when giving input ti this problem. The 1000 digit input given in the euler problem is given in 10 lines and you tend  to copy paste it directly into your input panel. Sometimes the IDE will only take the first 100 characters. To avoid the problem paste it in a notepad and delete all new line characters and copy paste it in your IDE.

I have done it for you.

7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Hope you didn't make this mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It worked...